# multiplicar elementos de una lista

Tags: python, lista

tengo el siguiente código:

```
numero=2
listanumeros=[1,2,3,4,5]
for i  in listanumeros:
    resultado=numero*i
    print(resultado)
```

esto hace que todos los elementos de la lista se multipliquen por 2
pregunta, si quisiera que cada elemento de la lista se multiplique por un número distinto
por ejemplo que el 1 se multiplique por 2 el 2 por 3 el 3 por 4 y así sucesivamente, como lo haría?

Comment: Esos numero distintos se donde salen? Se esta asumiendo que es una secuencia por ejemplo `listanumeros[i]+1`, es esto correcto?

Comment: Como menciona @GmrYael puedes realizar la  multiplicación con esa sentencia o en su caso puedes tener otra lista con los multiplicadores  y hacer la operación entre los elementos de ambas listas.

Answer (score 0):

Solución:

```
def mult(lista1, lista2):
    return [lista1[i] *  lista2[i] for i in range(len(lista1))]
```

La función recibe dos listas de igual largo y genera una tercera lista multiplicando cada elemento de `lista1` por el respectivo elemento en `lista2`.

#### Demo

```
def mult(lista1, lista2):
    return [lista1[i] *  lista2[i] for i in range(len(lista1))]

listanumeros=[1,2,3,4,5]
listamult=[2,3,4,5,6]

print(mult(listanumeros, listamult))
```

produce:

```
[2, 6, 12, 20, 30]

Process finished with exit code 0
```